# The minimum value of $|z-1+2i| + |4i-3-z|$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> The minimum value of $$|z-1+2i| + |4i-3-z|$$ is?

The only method of moving further that comes to my mind is assuming $$z=x+iy$$.

Comment: That is a reasonable approach and the one I use if I don't have a better idea.  What happened when you tried it?  You have a function of two real variables, compute it, take the derivatives, set to zero, and what happens?  There is an easier geometric approach if you think about what the absolute values represent.

Comment: An equation whose solution set is the segment $\overline{AB}$ is $\|A-P\|+\|P-B\| = \|A-B\|$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The sum of two distances of a point $z$ from two points is minimum when $z$ is between them.

Answer (score 1):

The  minimum is the distance between $1-2i$ and $3-4i$ which is 4$\sqrt {(3-1)^2+(-4+2)^2} = 2\sqrt 2 $$

This is when $z$ is on the segment joining the two points and $z$ is between them.

Answer (score 1):

You may proceed as follows:

You have

- $|z-a| + |z-b| \stackrel{!}{\rightarrow} \mbox{Min}$ with
- $a= 1-2i$ and $b = -3+4i$
  The triangle inequality gives immediately
  $$|z-a| + |z-b| \geq |z-a - (z-b)| = |b-a| = |-4 +6i| = 2\sqrt{13}$$

Note, that the minimum is attained when $z$ lies on the segment connecting $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of geometry in the complex plane:

1)$d:=$

$|z-(1-2i)| +|z-(-3+4i)|$ , $z=x+iy$.

$A(1,-2i)$, $B(-3,4i)$, $C(x,iy)$.

1) $A,B,C$ are not collinear.

In $\triangle ABC:$

$d= |AC|+|BC| >|AB|.

(Strict triangle inequality ).

2) $A,B,C$ are collinear.

a) $z$ is within the line segment $AB$,

then $d=|AB|$((why?).

b) $z$ is outside the line segment $|AB|$,

then $d>|AB|$(why?).